# IDE Arduino não abre no Windows 10 - Erro JAVA

Tags: java, arduino, windows-10

Instalei a `IDE` do `Arduino` no meu `Windows 10 64bits` e não estou conseguindo executar:

O *log* do *debug* dá este resultado

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino>arduino_debug.exe
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? O problema possivelmente pode estar nas `variáveis de ambiente`?

Obrigado!

Comment: instalei a IDE pela Windows Store, e eu não posso salvar uma sketch que o programa fecha, e o Minecraft Windows 10 Edition não abre kkk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JVM` não tem espaço suficiente em memória pra executar. Pelo *log*, tá reservando 256mb, então aumente a memória.

Execute o `arduino_debug.exe` com a *flag* `-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m`

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito tentar configurações das Variáveis de Ambientes no Windows, eu mudeis os valores do `_JAVA_OPTIONS` que ficou assim:

ANTES

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

DEPOIS

```
-Xmx512m -Xms256m -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Pelo que entendi, há uma mudança nos padrões desses valores, porém, só coloquei o valore do `Xms256m` para 512 e também mudei no final o `MaxPermSize` para 512, pois mesmo fora de uso, tenho algumas coisas que só rodam com esse valor setado.

Enfim, esta funcionando!

Answer (score -1):

é só ir em AppData/Local e apagar a pasta chamada arduino15, depois iniciar que ele recria o cache e funciona normalmente